# Jackson: Extract key, value pairs from map field when serializing object

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to serialize a pojo of the form:

```
public class Person
{
   private String firstName;

   private String lastName;

   private Map<String, String> details;
}
```

I am using the map since I don't have a limited amount of extra details. 
So if for example I instantiate the class as:

```
Map<String, String> details = new HashMap<>();
details.put("age", "20");
details.put("favouriteAnimal", "Unicorn");
Person person = new Person("A", "B", details);
```

I would like the json serialization to look like:

```
{
  "person": {
    "firstName": "A",
    "lastName": "B",
    "age": "20, 
    "favouriteAnimal": "Unicorn" 
  } 
}
```

Using Jackson, the 'default' serialized form is:

```
{
  "person": {
    "firstName": "A",
    "lastName": "B",
    "details": {
      "age": "20", 
      "favouriteAnimal": "Unicorn" 
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: what did you mean by "a limited amount of extra details"?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Extra details are optional, but in the case that they were added, I wanted them to appear next to the required ones: first and last name. The problem was that JsonUnwrapped does not support Map, and thus the map appeared as another entity, but using JsonAnyGetter solved the issue.

Comment: it surely will help, but why would you represent optional fields with a map in the first place? A map is a vague abstraction, and it may contain things barely related to a person instance. Why don't extend `Person` with other POJO classes where those optional fields would be defined?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko they are optional in the sense that I am not particularly interested in the content; it is loaded from a configuration file and matches a certain API, through this class I am only loading information, completing it, then passing it over as json to another API.